# Test if a variable is unset

Tags: shell

Is there a portable test for whether a variable (whose name is known statically in a script) is unset (which is different from empty)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For scalar variables, in standard (POSIX) `sh` syntax:

```
if [ "${var+set}" != set ]; then
  echo var is not set
fi
```

Or fancier albeit less legible things like

```
if [ -z "${var++}" ]; then
  echo var is unset
fi
```

Or:

```
if ${var+false}; then
  echo var is unset
fi
```

For array variables (not that arrays are *portable*), in `zsh` or `yash`, that would return unset unless the array is assigned any list including the empty list, while in bash or ksh that would return *unset* unless the element of index 0 is set. Same for associative arrays (for key "0").

Note that except in `zsh` (when not in `sh` emulation), `export var` or `readonly var` *declares* the variable but doesn't give it any value, so shells other than `zsh` will report `var` as `unset` there (unless `var` had been assigned a value before the call to `export`/`readonly`).

Comment: Also, `test -v var` in `bash` (and probably similar non-standard tests in other shells).

Comment: @PSkocik, `${var+set}` expands to `set`, not null when var is set regardless of the value. You can't use `${var-unset}` as  it would give a false positive if var contained unset.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Unset is what I meant. Thanks for the correction. (Wanted to take note of the mechanism in the comment.) ;-)

Comment: How does that last one not end up being a syntax error when `var` is set and `${var+false}` expands to nothing?  It behaves differently from `if ; then echo var is unset; fi`, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I suppose that's sort of similar to how commands with just assignments work, they reset the exit status to zero. `false; a=1; echo $?` prints `0`. The one here just doesn't have any assignments either, but a command with just the expansion is syntactically valid so it gets processed (unlike the totally empty command). There's this note at the end of [2.9.1 Simple Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01): _"Otherwise, the command shall complete with a zero exit status."_ which I suppose applies here.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I wouldn't use that in a real script though, I think the description "less legible" is certainly proper. :)

Comment: Thanks @ilkkachu (and I certainly agree about the "less legible" remark!)

Comment: At last `if [ "${var+set}" != set ]` is working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can I get an explanation of why the ++ notation works? It's unfortunately hard to search for

Comment: @ohshazbot, it's the same as `${var+set}` (which expands to `set` if `$var` is set even if to the empty string; and to the empty string otherwise), but using the `+` string instead of the `set` string. That's just an arbitrary string. The value doesn't matter so long as it's not empty (`[ -z` tests whether the following argument is empty or not).

Answer (score 0):

POSIX defines various parameter expansions to test if a parameter is unset.

- Look at the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)!

The following parameter expansion may be used to test if a parameter is not set. The second part (after the question mark) may be specified to indicate that the parameter `var` is unset.

```
echo ${var?parameter not set}
-sh: var: parameter not set
```

Note that it may be a programming error to use an undefined parameter.

```
prompt% sh -u script   # or set -o nounset
```

- Look at the `set` special built-in in the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25).

Comment: -1: If set -eu then this answer results in a script that fails and exits. Use the answer from Stéphane Chazelas above which works whether set -eu or not. Tested using dash.